# Is this note in Für Elise an E or a D?

Tags: piano, beethoven, editions

I've seen two notations for the note progression of Für Elise that goes "E.-C-B-A" at the end. One is "E.-C-B-A", which was the one I heard first, and the other is "D.-C-B-A", which appeared in an RCM book and which my piano teacher insisted was the "correct" version.

Which one is correct if any? The most commonly known one seems to be "E.-C-B-A".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is that book Urtext? If it is, it probably has some commentary which may or may not reveal something. The first edition of the piece is available on [IMSLP](http://imslp.org/), and has D in almost every case. The other versions seem to have E in every case, except one has D the very last time the figure appears.

Even if your book *is* urtext, it's not the-absolutely-correct-version. I've seen quite differing urtext editions of the same piece (some Chopin's valses come to mind; it's quite funny actually...). I would say usually urtext editions change when new data has come available, so your best bet is to try and find the most recent urtext possible and see what it tells you.

What you'll probably find in the commentary of an urtext version, if you find anything, is that it just lists which editions (including manuscripts, if available) contain which note, and maybe some argumentation why they picked the note they did. Just keep in mind that sometimes the composer wrote many different versions himself, and in any case he probably improvised a bit when he was playing, so I think one shouldn't think too much about it (like I often do).

Comment: +1 Maybe change "and has D in almost every case" into "and has D everywhere but the first time and its repeat" to be more specific?

Comment: No, it's an examination book, so I don't think it's Urtext.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Henle blog post](https://www.henle.de/blog/en/2011/11/30/beethoven-fur-elise-woo-59-%E2%80%93-do-you-strike-the-right-note/) on the subject, Henle settled on D rather than E based significantly on the existence of a handwritten Beethoven draft of the piece in which D is given.

[image: Beethoven manuscript showing D]
(IMAGE SOURCE: [Henle blog](https://www.henle.de/blog/en/2011/11/30/beethoven-fur-elise-woo-59-%E2%80%93-do-you-strike-the-right-note/))

Henle's full justification is not given on the blog. However, the manuscript draft combined with Nohl's consistent use of D in every parallel moment (mm. 22, 46, 60, 90, and 104), is highly suggestive the D is intended in every instance. There's no evident musical reason why Beethoven would have given E in m. 7 but D in every other.